# Should I be worried about the RVM warning about Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rvm

To what degree should I be worried about the following warning that is displayed after installing Ruby 1.8.7-head via RVM:

> Please be aware that you just installed a ruby that requires 2 patches
>   just to be compiled on up to date linux system. This may have known
>   and unaccounted for security vulnerabilities.

Comment: What do you think? This is the build system telling you using software past it's best-by date.

Comment: So how all are answering it, you mean it's just a hint that it would be better to use ruby 1.9 (or now, 2.0) - but if one has an application that has not yet been migrated to work on ruby 1.9/2.0, then how can one obtain and install the "2 patches" this warning mentions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Someone thought it was important enough to write that for people to read. Ruby is a fast moving language and 1.8.7 is all but dead. I would suggest 1.9.2 if you like something a little more slow moving, or 1.9.3 if you like living on the edge.

Comment: Development on 1.8.7 might have ceased, but it's still the default system ruby on several systems.  There are still good reasons to need to be using it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're using it for.  We use rvm to build 1.8.7-series rubies so that we can develop on a recent OS but deploy conservatively.  For instance, the ruby on Debian Squeeze is ruby-1.8.7-p302, and it's important to us to know that our code works there as written, no matter what OS we're individually developing on.  In this case, I'd ignore that warning.

If you're using RVM to provide your production ruby, I'd pay more attention.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need 1.8.7 but want a slightly more updated and optimized version you might want to check out REE  http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/

Comment: you can always `rvm install ree` - it's easier to remember and keep up to date: `rvm upgrade ree` - if new version available will ask if upgrade, if not - will fail

Comment: If the OP is worried about security s/he'll at least be good for another year(till June 2013) according to your link Enabren. So I guess it might still be a more viable option.